# Prove $X\times Y$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

(Relation between two sets) If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, a relation between $X$ and $Y$ is a subset $R \subset X \times Y.$ For a relation $R \subset X\times Y$ and $a \in X$ and $b \in Y$ if $(x,y) \in R,$ we write $xRy$ and if $(x,y)\notin R,$ we write $x/R/y.$ (let /R/ be a slash across the R similar to what I have with $\notin$.)

My question:

Prove that $X \times Y$ is an equivalence relation. We have that there is a relation $R$ on $X$ and another relation $R'$ on $Y$ and that both are equivalence relations. The goal is to prove that $R \times R'$ is an equivalence relation.

My thoughts: I am trying to teach this to myself. Some friend of mine was talking about this and I did not know too much about these types of question. I decided to learn this by myself and saw this question.

How would we do this? Can someone please help me with this? I would like to see how this proof is done.

This is what Hugh Denoncourt was saying in his comment.

Comment: reflexive, transitive, symmetric relation == equivalence relation.

Comment: @tp1 I know, but how would we show this though in this Cantor $X \times Y$ set. I need the help to understand how to do this at this level. Can you help me?

Comment: @André Nicolas I am trying to prove this but am having trouble. Is there anyway you can help me?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right relation? Equivalence relations are typically from a set to itself. Is it assumed that $X = Y$?

Comment: @HughDenoncourt I editted my question.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt I want to prove $X\times Y$ is an equivalence relation. Can we use that an equivalence relation is a relation between members of the same set?

Comment: Your edit has not clarified what is being asked. My best guess is that you have a relation $R$ on $X$ and another relation $R'$ on $Y$ and that both are equivalence relations. It sounds like the goal is to prove that the product relation $R \times R'$ is an equivalence relation. But that isn't stated in your theorem and the preamble makes it sound like the relation $R$ is from $X$ to $Y$ where $X \neq Y$ is a possibility. Where is this theorem stated? Have you faithfully reproduced it?

Comment: If the relation is on $X \times Y$, then you have to specify how two pairs are related. When is $(x,y)$ related to $(x',y')$? This is nowhere in your question.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt Yes I am trying to prove exactly what you said in your comment. I'm sorry about this because a friend of mine started talking about this and I wanted to learn about this and you can edit my question if you want. Is it ok if you show me. Again, I'm sorry. I will vote for you.

Comment: No, that's okay. It's not about the votes or anything for me anyway. It'd be weird to edit the question to what I *think* is being asked and then to answer it. I really think you should re-post with the exact text of the problem instead of referring users to my comment. (More ambiguities! Which comment?)

Comment: @HughDenoncourt Ok, I will. Is it ok if you can show me a proof of this while I do the edit? It would really help.